# How to find TargetPath/executable path of a project using .sln and .proj file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

I have `.sln` file and `proj` file.
Is there any way to find the `TargetPath` or `Exectable file path` of a project under a solution using `.sln` and `.proj` (example: .csproj, .wixproj, .vbproj etc) file?

Comment: Actually, you can write a target into `xxx.proj` file to get these specific properties in msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to find the TargetPath or Exectable file path of a
>   project under a solution using .sln and .proj (example: .csproj,
>   .wixproj, .vbproj etc) file?

You could write a target to execute message task to show these properties in your specific project.

Since you want to get TargetPath and Exectable file path (MSBuild properties) in specific project, you can write this in your `xxx.csproj`/`xxx.vbproj` file to show these:

**TargetPath** means `$(TargetPath)` while **Exectable file path** means `$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)` in MSBuild to get their specific values

```
<Target Name="findproperty" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="TargetPath is ====$(TargetPath)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Exectable file path is ====$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)"></Message>
</Target>
```

And then when you build your project, you can see it in Output Window when you build your project:

[image]

**Note** that `xxx.sln` file is used to contain the current each `xxx.proj` is associated with various projects, it can not use MSBuild Properties, target, etc. If you want to write, only write in `xxx.proj` file.

In other types of projects, targetpath or Exectable file path may be replaced by other proeprties, so specific analysis should be done according to other types of projects.

Hope it could help you.